# Ag-grid: Full width grouping rows with tree data

Tags: ag-grid

I am using tree data in my Ag-Grid.  Is it possible to have the grouping row displayed as full width, like you can for regular [row grouping](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#full-width-groups-rendering)?  Have tried what is suggested in that link, but the grouping column then disappears.